# Expected semicolon in dynamically created form element

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a php script which will:
1. Connect to a database
2. Query the database for a string input by the user
3. Display each row returned by the query as a dynamically created form. Each form has two 'hidden' input fields, which will be used to populate a separate page with some images and text. The form is submitted through a link, which uses the onclick attribute in conjunction with the javascript 'document.form.submit()' to handle submitting the form.

The problem that I'm having is that each form created causes the page to throw a 'semicolon expected' error, stating that I should have a semicolon in the middle of a word in my code! I am 99.99% certain that whatever is causing this error is somewhere in the code below, but I've been staring at it for quite a while now and I'm stumped.

```
// Run a query against each field to search for input
foreach($columns as $field){
$searchquery = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE '.$field.' LIKE \'%'.$input.'%\'';
$results = $db->Execute($searchquery);

// We introduce HTML formatting for each result in $results
foreach($results as $resultset) {
    echo '<div style="border: 2px solid black;">';

    // Each result in $results is an array, where the keys and values correspond to the field names and values of the table
    foreach($resultset as $key=>$value) {
        if($key == 'ID'){ // Query the database by ID for the rows returned by the previous query
            $resultquery = 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM mytable WHERE '.$key.' = \''.$value.'\'';
            $row = $db->Execute($resultquery);
            $row = explode(",", $row);
            $id = $row[2];
            $company = $row[3];
            $prodname = $row[4];
            echo "<form name='rowForm.$i' action='page.php' method='POST'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='Company' value='$company'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='ProductName' value='$prodname'>";
            echo "<a href='path/to/my/page' onclick='javascript:document.rowForm.$i.submit(); return false;'> $company - $prodname ($id) </a>";
            echo "</form>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Fyi, $columns is an array which holds the names of all columns in my table. All of the forms get displayed correctly, and everything looks as it should; the only issue being that the links don't work correctly, due to this semicolon error. I'm confident that I've posted all the relevant code, but feel free to let me know if it looks like there's something missing. If anyone can point me in the right direction on this I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT: Here's the html code which is generated by the php above, with some additional whitespace added and the actual values for some variables replaced with {$varname's value} for readibility. Note that this code is generated for each row returned by the sql query.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid black;">
    <form name='rowForm.0' action='page.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Company' value='{$company's value}'>
        <input type='hidden' name='ProductName' value='{$prodname's value}'>
        <a href='http://link/to/my/site' onclick='javascript:document.forms[\'rowForm.0\'].submit(); return false;'> {This is the link text} </a>
    </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing brace for one of your foreach loops :)

Comment: What kind of class/object _is_ `$db`?

Comment: Yep, the first foreach isn't being closed... :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies everyone. 
@ Problematic: The code that I posted is only a snippet of the whole code; I've only included the part which is relevant to the problem I'm having. The foreach loop is closed, I just forgot to include the closing brace in my post :P
@Wrikken: $db is just how I'm connecting to my database, through a method provided by the CMS I'm using (concrete5). I'm absolutely positive that it's not causing any issues though.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Including stack trace, etc.

Comment: @Problematic: The error I'm getting isn't a php error; it's an error on the webpage itself. In other words, the following appears in a popup window: Errors in this webpage might cause it to work incorrectly  
Expected ';'  
page-name line: 90  
Code: 0 char: 17  
URI: http://yougettheidea...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but I guess the characters you are trying to escape in single-quotes aren't being escaped. You should write it like that instead:

```
$searchquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE " .$field. " LIKE '% ". $input . "%'";

$resultquery = "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM mytable WHERE " .$key. " = '" . $value . "'";
```

---

// edit:

My bad, I got the escaping-thing not quite right:

> ```
> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

---

And, as already mentioned, your code above is missing a `}` at the bottom to close the first `foreach` ;)

Comment: "Escaping characters with \ within a string only works between double-quotes." ... What?

Comment: The escape sequences are [expanded in double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), normal escapes of course apply....

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there are no issues in the queries, especially since the results of those queries are used/displayed exactly as I expect them to, not to mention the time I spent trying to get all my php/sql to co-operate with my cms. Thanks anyway though :P

Answer (score 0):

Does this:

```
document.rowForm.$i.submit()
```

Amount to this in the HTML source?

```
document.rowForm..submit()
```

... cause then I can see a problem...

If not, I'd still go with:

```
document.forms['rowForm.$i'].submit()
```

Comment: ...huh. While the $i variable was getting included correctly in the html source, changing the line to your suggested syntax resulted in a change in the error I get - now it's just a 'syntax error' at the beginning of the line, which at least makes a little more sense than what I was getting :P

Comment: Haha never mind, changing the syntax in that line just gave me an issue with nested strings in the html source, which caused the change in the error message.

Comment: Could you perhaps put the relevant portion of the HTML source somewhere? Saves us guessing what PHP variables are set or not :)